# Inflection points with natural logs.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Where are the inflection points, if any exist, for $f(x)=10\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}$?
I don't think any exist. But could use a little help. My guess would be that with the second derivative, if $x = e^{-2}$ you get 0, but this is not in the domain of the function. Is this correct, or completely off? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should solution be symbolic/theoretic, or numerical?

Answer (score 2):

Inflection point *must* exist.

Indeed we have a maximum at $x=e^e$ and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$, therefore concavity must change because $f(x)$ has no intersection with $x$-axis after $x=e$.

We have $$f''(x)=10\,\frac{ (\log x+2) \log (\log x)-\log x-3}{x^2 \log ^3x}$$

$f''(x)=0$ if $$(\log x+2) \log (\log x)-\log x-3=0$$
substitute $\log x=u$
$$(u+2)\log u-u-3=0\to u=3.28455$$
Finally we have $x=e^{3.28455}\approx 26.7$

the graph below shows the curve $y=f(x)$, the inflection point and the tangent

---

$$...$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First $e^{-2}$ doesn't belong to the domain of $f$.

Using Geogebra, you can be convinced that the second derivative does cancel.
$$f''(x)=10\frac{\ln x\ln(\ln x))-\ln x+2\ln(\ln x)-3}{x^2\ln^3x}$$
The numerator can be studied, it's a strictly increasing function with limits $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ at the extremities of the domain. So it has to cancel once, and there you find an inflexion point for the curve of your function.

Comment: So I just work out where the numerator equals 0?

Comment: No, you just say it *has* to cancel. The exact solution doesn't seem to be easy to find :-P

Comment: This question is a basis for drawing a curve, the exact answer is needed unfortunately.

Comment: We usually say "vanish" in English, rather than "cancel".

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the solution to $f''(x)=0$ occurs at $e^{e^x}$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is the (only) solution to

$$xe^x-e^x+2x-3=0$$

We may rewrite the equation above as $(x-1)(e^x-2)=1$, but I'm not sure how much better this is actually.

I see no reason to assume that $x$ has a 'nice' symbolical representation

Comment: x ≈ 1.189230743274938146405625269207614188688490400225224705

Comment: Exp[Exp[x]] ≈ 26.6970632944226770241694734645795695062900028984103052466584860355629\
999441118276947854895736248776